# FullCalendar Does not re-render after updateEvents

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

My goal is to have 2 different FullCalendar elements that stay in sync.  I'm not doing ANY network calls, simply client side arrays at this point.

When I add an event (say through a click or just right after it's built) the calendar does not actually re-render as the documentation claims.

I've also attempted to use the "renderEvents" and "renderEvent" flavors but that seems unnecessary since "updateEvents" would/should update the rendering of these events.  The problem I also ran into is the "renderEvent" on the list version of the calendar does not show the event I'm adding if it's out of the range of that calendar.

```
const events = [{
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: TODAY
  },
  {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: TODAY,
    end: NEXTDAY
  }
]

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  events
})

$("#events").fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  defaultView: 'listMonth',
  events
})

// Now add a new one
events.push([{
  title: 'Event added',
  start: YESTERDAY
}])

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvents', events)
$('#events').fullCalendar('updateEvents', events)
```

Here's a recreation of the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/7d92utp5/

The use case is pretty simple:  Add a new event to the list of events, render the events on the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly change your pushing event to object from array.

```
events.push({
   title: 'Event added',
   start: YESTERDAY
});
```

Now, you have many choice to do that. I will write 2 way for you.

**a.**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7d92utp5/49/

**b.** 1) Change *events* param to function

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  // at here
  events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    callback(events);
  }
});
```

2) Use *refetchEvents* instead *updateEvents*

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7d92utp5/53/

Comment: Fantastic this worked.  Do you or anyone know what https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvents (updateEvents) actually does?

Comment: It may not do that. You can read the docs from here: [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvent) It might update the current events. Ex: an event's title changed

Comment: Fair, I glanced at the single "update event" docs but looking at the "update events" docs it didn't say anything about updating ONLY the existing ones.  Just an error in the docs maybe.

Answer (score 0):

### **For fullCalendar v3, you can apply this way to re-render calendar:**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
// calendar options...
});

// Rerender the calendar
function rerenderCalendar() {
// Destroy the calendar
calendar.fullCalendar('destroy');

// Reinitialize the calendar with new options or updated events
calendar.fullCalendar({
// new calendar options...
});
}

// Call the rerenderCalendar function whenever you want to rerender the calendar
rerenderCalendar();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).